# Looping through a column of one dataframe while maintaining another dataframe when passing to function with 2 arguments

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe

I have several large dataframes with over 6 million observations & 10 variables at the moment, but for convenience let's assume I have two simplified data frames at the moment:

df1:

```
    A     B     C
1   1     0     2
2   2     3     5
```

df2:

```
    D
1   6
2   10
```

& I have a function with two arguments:

```
example_fn <- function(x,y){
  return(x+y)
}
```

What I would like to do, specifically, is **looping through columns of df1** to be passed into example_fn, while **df2 is retained**

P/S: I am used to using lapply for looping when function contains just one argument, but now that there are two I am unsure of what to do

Please advise & thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you need a `map` e.g `Map(example_fn,df1,df2)`? Also take a look at `purrr` and `plyr`(haven't used this in a while though, seems to have lost favor).

Comment: Can you share your expected result? If possible can you also dput a portion of your data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `df2` is retained and we only need to iterate over columns of `df1`, we can still use `lapply`.

```
lapply(df1, example_fn, df2$D)
#Or call it explicitly
#lapply(df1, function(x) example_fn(x, df2$D))
#$A
#[1]  7 12

#$B
#[1]  6 13

#$C
#[1]  8 15
```

which can be called in similar way using `purrr::map`

```
purrr::map(df1, example_fn, df2$D)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Map` from `base` or `map2` from `purrr`:

```
Map(function(x,y) x+y, df1,df2)
```

With `purrr`:

```
purrr::map2_df(df1,df2,function(x,y) x+y)
```

Using `mapply` and `mtcars` for reproducibility:

```
head(mapply(function(x,y) x + y, mtcars, mtcars))
      mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
[1,] 42.0  12  320 220 7.80 5.24 32.92  0  2    8    8
[2,] 42.0  12  320 220 7.80 5.75 34.04  0  2    8    8
[3,] 45.6   8  216 186 7.70 4.64 37.22  2  2    8    2
[4,] 42.8  12  516 220 6.16 6.43 38.88  2  0    6    2
[5,] 37.4  16  720 350 6.30 6.88 34.04  0  0    6    4
[6,] 36.2  12  450 210 5.52 6.92 40.44  2  0    6    2
```